# New user. Reason for downvotes on question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Prove the following relation (using Fourier analysis)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3127599/prove-the-following-relation-using-fourier-analysis)

This is my first time on Mathematics Stack Exchange. I didn't think my question was vague, and I did try to solve it on my own for quite a long time before asking here. So I'm puzzled by the downvotes I've received. I don't know where I went wrong. Maybe I should have added a tag for Poisson-summation-formula? But then if I knew that I wouldn't need to ask the question in the first place.
I would like to know what I did wrong so that I don't repeat the same mistake again. Thank you.

Comment: Your "question" was (and still is) phrased as a command. This is not a good approach when you are asking people for help.

Answer (score 14):

Before asking the question you should have been shown a page that starts after some greeting:

> To improve the chances of your question getting an answer, make sure that it:
>
> - Uses MathJax formatting for math formulas
> - Has an interesting, specific title that summarizes the question
> - Describes what you know and what you don't understand (don't just copy a textbook problem!)

You confirmed that you'll keep this in mind. You did the first, yet not the two others. This is the reason why you face problems. The page I mentioned contained links to more detailed instructions. For example [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) especially the answer on "Provide Context."

The information you provided later in in a comment would have been a good addition to your original post. You can still include it via an edit.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I tried to summarize and describe it to my best. I was looking at it from a pure Fourier analysis point of view, so I mentioned just that in the question. I will try to be better next time onwards. Thank you for taking the time to respond to a question that gets asked a lot.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to the site! The site can sometimes seem unforgiving, but if one manages to avoid some pitfalls, things usually work out well.